# Two applications with different log4j2.xml are trying to log into same logfile

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j, log4j2

I am running two applications, A and B. B has runtime dependency on A. Both applications have their own log4j2.xml files containing log file name and other information.

B has some preinstallation script and is executed by 'root' user before A. It creates its own log file b_log.log When A starts, it try to log into b_log.log instead of creating its own logfile. A is started by different user 'a_user'. So A gets 'permission denied' error because it is not able to access and log into b_log.log created by 'root'. Both logfiles use RollingRandomAccessFile  appender.

How can I make both applications log into separate log files? Providing separate log4j2.xml  is not working.

log4j2.xml of Application A:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO">
    <Appenders>
        <RollingRandomAccessFile name="ApplicationFile" fileName="${sys:logPath}/log_a.log"
                     filePattern="${sys:logPath}/log_a.log".%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-5level] (%t) %X{sessionId} %c{1}: %msg%n"/>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
            </Policies>
        </RollingRandomAccessFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="ApplicationFile"/>
        </Root>

        <!-- Loggers explicitly defined here, so their levels could be adjusted in runtime via JMX -->
        <Logger name="com.xyz.a.package" level="INFO" />
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

log4j2.xml of application B:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO">
    <Appenders>
        <RollingRandomAccessFile name="LogB" fileName="${sys:logPath}/log_b.log"
                     filePattern="$${sys:logPath}/log_b.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-5level] (%t) %X{sessionId} %c{1}: %msg%n"/>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
            </Policies>
        </RollingRandomAccessFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="com.xyz.b.package" level="INFO" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="LogB"/>
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Exception that application A is not able to access b_log:

```
    2017-03-12 07:42:37,197 main ERROR Cannot access RandomAccessFile java.io.FileNotFoundException: /app/env/Service/var/output/logs/log_b.log (Permission denied) java.io.FileNotFoundException: /app/env/Service/var/output/logs/log_b.log (Permission denied)
            at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)
            at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:316)
            at java.io.RandomAccessFile.(RandomAccessFile.java:243)
            at java.io.RandomAccessFile.(RandomAccessFile.java:124)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingRandomAccessFileManager$RollingRandomAccessFileManagerFactory.createManager(RollingRandomAccessFileManager.java:176)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingRandomAccessFileManager$RollingRandomAccessFileManagerFactory.createManager(RollingRandomAccessFileManager.java:149)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractManager.getManager(AbstractManager.java:73)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.getManager(OutputStreamManager.java:81)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingRandomAccessFileManager.getRollingRandomAccessFileManager(RollingRandomAccessFileManager.java:82)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingRandomAccessFileAppender.createAppender(RollingRandomAccessFileAppender.java:207)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:132)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:918)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:858)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:850)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:479)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:219)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:231)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:496)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:566)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:582)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:217)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:152)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:45)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:194)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getContext(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:122)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getContext(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:34)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:46)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:89)
            at java.util.logging.LogManager.demandLogger(LogManager.java:551)
            at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:455)
            at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:502)
            at com.sun.jmx.remote.util.ClassLogger.(ClassLogger.java:55)
            at sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap.(ConnectorBootstrap.java:846)
            at sun.management.Agent.startAgent(Agent.java:257)
            at sun.management.Agent.startAgent(Agent.java:447)

    2017-03-12 07:42:37,209 main ERROR Unable to invoke factory method in class class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingRandomAccessFileAppender for element RollingRandomAccessFile. java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
```

Comment: Letting two applications use the same log file seems to be a bad practice.

Comment: I don't actually see a question here. What do you want to know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can share the same Log4j2 configuration file and still log to different log files by making (part of) the file appender path a system property and giving each application a different value for the property.

A simple example looks like this:

```
<Appenders>
  <File name="ApplicationLog" fileName="${sys:logPath}/app.log"/>
</Appenders>
```

Information on how to use Lookups in configuration files can be found in the [Property Substitution](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#PropertySubstitution) section of the [Configuration](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html) page.

---

Update:
Note that if the logging *directory* is created by a process running as root then other processes running as other users will likely not have permissions to create files in that directory...

This is not a Log4j2 issue though. You need to ensure that the target directory has the correct permissions.

---

Update 2:
To summarize the problem: Application B runs first and creates b_log.log.   Next application A runs. You specified a different Log4j2 configuration but *for some reason application A picks up the Log4j2 configuration from application B*, and application A also tries (incorrectly) to log to b_log.log. This fails because of permissions. The problem is not that A *cannot* write to b_log.log, but it should not be trying to write to that file: it has the wrong configuration.

If the above is correct then the problem is how to prevent the 2nd application "A" from picking the wrong configuration. You can accomplish this by starting the 2nd application with system property `-Dlog4j.configurationFile=path/to/log4j2.xml` to tell it exactly what configuration file to use.

Comment: Thanks Remko. It is working if I use single logfile for both applications. Since these applications are different I was thinking of keeping their logging configuration separate. Could I make these applications use different log4j2.xml and log into different logfiles?

Comment: Thanks for response. The solution you suggested is not working. I have added log4j2.xml of both applications in the question.

Comment: The log_b.log file is created by root, not directory. So I think this is not permission problem. The other users are able to write files into that directory. Do you think classloader is loading first application's(B) log4j2.xml and using it for other application(A) ?. Jars of application A and B are in the same directory

Comment: You said 2 applications. I assumed that means 2 processes. Are you talking about a web container like tomcat or something?

Comment: The main application (A) is spring application which runs in custom server. Application B is standalone application and run by a script before A starts.

Comment: Attached stack trace. Thanks

Comment: Provided another answer.